# Query Activity last email sent to subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud

I need to be able to use query activity to figure out the last email sent to a subscriber and if it was sent via a sendable DE then what is the name of the DE

_Sent dataview gives me the details on the last email sent.  however, where can i find the details on if the email was sent via a sendable de and what is the name of the de.

Answer (score 0):

I have good news and bad news, and maybe some more good news..  The good news is you can query against the ListID in _Sent and figure out if it is a List or a DE.  (A List will have a legit ID, DE will be null or zero, I don't remember which)  The bad news, if we're talking past tense, meaning you want to get the DE name for things you've already sent, it's too late, and you're going to need to get a services engagement with the SF Marketing Cloud to get that DE name for past sends.  If its not past tense and maintaining the DE name is something you wish to do going, then there is more good news: have a look at the [send logging feature.](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/)